# On right-click, Send keyboard command using highlighted text

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My company uses [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) to access various aspects of orders on our system. Countless times every day I manually input numbers from our tracking system. I would like to expedite the process, but I am a total beginner and don't really know where to start. I am not even sure if this is a feasible extension to create, so any information pointing me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

In a nutshell I would like to:

- Highlight text
- Right Click
- Send key command: Alt+Space 
  (this is the configurable command I input to open my launchy window)
- Input highlighted text
- Send key: Enter

As far as I can tell, the extension would just need to add an option to my right click menu (which I am hoping is an easy task)

I hope this isn't too vague of a question for this site. I am not looking for a full solution. Just some general guidance and perhaps an example to work from.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done using only a Chrome Extension, but it can be done using a Chrome Extension,  `nativeMessaging` and a native program (like a Python script)